# MySQL 8: How do I create columns from FKs?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

[context] I need to return rows that describe the current state of all machines in a table that records changes in that machine's state:

Raw data:

| Timestamp | Machine ID | fkDataType | Data Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-17 23:28:28 | 1001 | 8 | False |
| 2021-02-17 23:28:28 | 1001 | 6 | False |
| 2021-02-17 23:28:28 | 1001 | 2 | O9009 |
| 2021-02-17 23:28:28 | 1001 | 5 | 1 |
| 2021-01-14 00:44:02 | 2001 | 9 | Test Message |

DataTypes:

| ID | DataTypeName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mode |
| 2 | Program |
| 3 | PartCount |
| 4 | PartGoal |
| 5 | Pallet |
| 6 | HasAlarm |
| 7 | AlarmContents |
| 8 | HasMessage |
| 9 | MessageContents |

Currently, I have a query that gets the most recent data for each data type for each machine, but I do not know how to put each datatype in its own column.

```
WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT t1.MachineName, fkNodeID as MachineID, DataValue, fkDataType as DataType, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY fkDataType, fkNodeID ORDER BY id DESC) AS Recency
    FROM MachineData.Transactions
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MachineID, MachineName FROM MachineData.Machines
    ) t1 WHERE t1.MachineID = fkNodeID
)
SELECT * FROM ranked WHERE Recency = 1
ORDER BY MachineID, DataType
```

Sample of my query:

| Machine Name | ID | Data Value | fkDataType | Recency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | Memory | 1 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | O9009 | 2 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | 167 | 3 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | 200 | 4 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | False | 6 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | "" | 7 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | False | 8 | 1 |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | "" | 9 | 1 |
| ESP32 | 2001 | Test Message | 9 | 1 |

Desired Output:

| Machine Name | ID | Mode | Program | PartCount | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Enshu GE480H | 1001 | Memory | O9009 | 167 | ... |
| ESP32 | 2001 | null | null | null | ... |

I am lost on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. [MySQL version: 8.0]

Comment: Lots of examples in [pivot-table]